# How to create a serial pipe between a windows host and virtual machine in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, serial-port

I am trying to debug the kernel of a windows 7 virtual machine and am following the steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj200334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Windows_Kernel_Debugging).

I ran:

```
bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial debugport:n baudrate:115200
```

on the virtual machine and have set up the port to a named pipe:

[image: serial port setup]

but when I reboot the machine I get:

[image: serial pipe error]

How can I create the pipe inside the guest machine (both the host and the guest are running windows 7)?

Answer (score 4):

You set **Host pipe**. It means you need to fill pipe name like this: *\.\pipe\VirtualMachineName*

Moreover, as **Robin Hood** mentioned you need to uncheck **Connect to existing pipe/socket** it helps don't create a pipe manually. After launch *Virtual machine* you can check created pipe via [pipelist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist) application. You should see VirtualMachineName on the list.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pipelist64.exe
...
pipe_returnb2848f45-49cf-444b-85a1-04af7fe5606e          1              128
mojo.9004.8732.10216662671524970515                      1                1
mojo.9004.9560.12163195199288806074                      1                1
mojo.9004.9560.2084235546261883787                       1                1
VirtualMachineName                                       1                1
```

You can read what is **pipe** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). A pipe isn't a simple file.

Answer (score 3):

it is not an existing port, uncheck connect to existing pipe, so it creates a new one.

Thanks